# Computing: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\frac{1}{x}}\left(3^\frac{1}{x}-5^\frac{-1}{x}\right)}{\log_2(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\frac{1}{x}}\left(3^\frac{1}{x}-5^\frac{-1}{x}\right)}{\log_2(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3})}$$

I'm not sure whether my solution is correct.

$t:=\frac{1}{x}$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\frac{1}{x}}\left(3^\frac{1}{x}-5^\frac{-1}{x}\right)}{\log_2(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3})}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 t}\left(3^t-5^{-t}\right)}{\log_2(1+t^2+t^3)}$$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{\sqrt t^2}\cdot t\cdot\left(\frac{3^t-1}{t}\cdot t+(-t)\frac{(-5)^{-t}+1}{-t}\right)}{\log_2(1+t^2+t^3)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}(\ln 3+\ln 5)\left[\lim_{t\to 0}\log_2(1+t^2+t^3)^\frac{1}{t^2}\right]^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(\ln3+\ln 5)\left(e^{{\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^2+t^3}{t^2}}^{-1}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\ln3+\ln5}{2e}$$

Comment: This exact question has been asked very recently but I can't find it. If you don't want to use L'Hopital you might interested in using Taylor approximations.

Comment: The fundamentals of your solution look correct, i.e. your choices to isolate $\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos^2(t)}{t^2}}$ and $\frac{3^t - 1}{t}$ & $\frac{\frac{1}{5}^t - 1}{t}$ in the numerator. I would double check your steps after that. which I didn't completely follow.

Comment: @lmc, you have a typo, there is $\cos^3{\frac{1}{x}}$, at least in the exam (: Look:$$$$https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/nastava/analiza/kolokviji/analiza1_1617_kol2.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is very good; the limit you get is for $t\to0^+$, so $\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}=\sin t$ and you get
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t(3^t-5^{-t})}{\log_2(1+t^2+t^3)}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t}{t}\frac{3^t-5^{-t}}{t}\frac{t^2\log 2}{\log(1+t^2+t^3)}
$$
(where “log” denotes the natural logarithm) and you can compute separately the limit of the three factors. The first is known to be $1$. Then
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{3^t-5^{-t}}{t}=\log 3+\log 5
$$
because it's the derivative at $0$ of $f(t)=3^t-5^{-t}$. Alternatively, write it as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\frac{3^t-1}{t}+\frac{5^t-1}{t}\frac{1}{5^t}\right)
$$
and use the fundamental limits (which is basically what you did).

For the last one, apply l’Hôpital (or Taylor):
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{2t\log2}{\dfrac{2t+3t^2}{1+t^2+t^3}}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{2(1+t^2+t^3)\log2}{2+3t}=\log2
$$
So finally you get $(\log3+\log5)\log2=(\log 15)(\log 2)$

Comment: may I ask how the end would look like if there were $\sqrt{1-\cos^3{\frac{1}{x}}}$? Because it says so in the original paper. I had a different idea and tried this:$$\log_2(f(x))=\frac{\ln(f(x))}{\ln2}$$
$$t:=\frac{1}{x}$$
$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\sqrt{1-\cos^3t}=\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt{(1-\cos t)(1+\cos t+\cos^2 t)}=\sqrt{3}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{1+\cos t}=\sqrt{3}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{1}=\sqrt{3}\lim_{t\to 0}(1-\cos t)$, $$$$but $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t}$ lead me on a totally wrong track.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya $\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt{1-\cos^3t}=0$, so this doesn't help, does it?

Comment: It does, everything is clear, but I didn't know how to get rid of the square root correctly, in terms of substituting the expression under the root by something else.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya $\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^3t}}{t}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}(1+\cos t+\cos^2t)}=\sqrt{3/2}$

Comment: thank you, just in case: since limits commute with continuous functions, I can get it this way: $\sqrt{\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}}=\sqrt{\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin t}{2t}}=\sqrt{\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\cos t}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya If you prefer this, OK; but it's essentially the Taylor expansion at degree 2.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\frac{1}{x}}
(3^\frac{1}{x}-5^\frac{-1}{x})}{\log_2(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3})}
&=\dfrac{\sin(1/x)
(e^\frac{\ln 3}{x}-e^\frac{-\ln 5}{x})}{(1/\ln 2)\ln(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3})}\\
&=\dfrac{(1/x+O(1/x^3))
((1+\ln 3/x+O(1/x^2)-(1-\ln 5/x+O(1/x^2))}{(1/\ln 2)(x^{-2}+x^{-3}+O(x^{-4})}\\
&=\dfrac{(1/x+O(1/x^3))
((\ln 3+\ln 5)/x+O(1/x^2))\ln 2}{x^{-2}(1+O(x^{-3}))}\\
&=\dfrac{1+O(1/x))
((\ln 3+\ln 5)+O(1/x))\ln 2}{1+O(1/x)}\\
&=(\ln 2(\ln 15)+O(1/x))(1+O(1/x))\\
&=(\ln 2)(\ln 15)+O(1/x)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Err, what is $O$?

Comment: "big-oh" notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1):

**Fast solution:**

Using the minimum number of terms of the Taylor developments,
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin t\,(e^{t\log 3}-e^{-{t\log 5}})}{\log_2(1+t^2+t^3)}$$ has

- at the numerator a factor $t$, and the difference between $1+t \log3$ and $1-t\log 5$;
- at the denominator, $\dfrac{t^2}{\log2}$.

Hence the limit is

$$\log2\log15.$$

---

**Without Taylor,**

we can replace $\sin t$ by $t$ (thanks to the limit of $\dfrac{\sin t}t$), and $e^{t\log 3}-e^{-t\log 5}$ by $e^{t\log 15}-1$ by pulling out a factor $e^{-5t\log 5}$. Then $e^{t\log 15}-1=\dfrac{e^{t\log 15}-1}{t\log 15}t\log 15$ can be replaced by $t\log 15$.

Then $\lim_{t\to0}\log(1+t^2+t^3)=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\log(1+t^2+t^3)}{t^2+t^3}(t^2+t^3)$.

Finally, we have

$$\log2\log15\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^2}{t^2+t^3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using Taylor series or applying L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\left(3^{\frac{1}{x}}-5^{\frac{-1}{x}}\right)}{\log_{2}\left(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3}\right)}$$$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\color{blue}{\frac{1}{x}}}\cdot\frac{\color{blue} {x^{-2}+x^{-3}}}{\log_{2}\left(1+x^{-2}+x^{-3}\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{3^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{\color{blue} {\frac{1}{x}}}+\frac{5^{\frac{-1}{x}}-1}{\color{blue}{\frac{-1}{x}}}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\color{blue}{x^{-1}+1}}$$$$=\ln\left(2\right)\ln\left(15\right)$$